# Error: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal for request API tool

Tags: api, eof, payload

I am using an API tool by this codes. but I received this error : EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal

```
url =  baseUrl + "NamedEntityRecognition/Detect"
payload = u"\""+Sentences+"}"
result = json.loads(callApi(url, payload, tokenKey))
for phrase in result:
    print("("+phrase['word']+","+phrase['tags']['NER']['item1']+") ")
```

Comment: This does not seem like all the code. What is `payload` supposed to look like?

Comment: You're missing a tag as to what language you're attempting to use, but I'll parse it as language agnostic as possible.

What is "u" that you're setting in `payload`? Without the u in front, it seems like you're trying to set a string of some sort, but that is going to end up looking . like this: `""This text is whatever Sentences is.}"`. 

This means that your `payload` variable has 2 double quotes at the start and one close brace and one double quote at the end. And this assumes that Sentences doesn't have additional characters in it that could further complicate it. Is this intended?

Comment: The language is persian

Comment: lats comment is the codes from demo of text-mining which I used its APIs.

Comment: below codes I applied for sentence splitting and they worked. I tried to follow the method in current codes for named entity recognition API tool.

Comment: url =  baseUrl + "PreProcessing/NormalizePersianWord"
payload = u"{\"text\":\""+Text+"\", \"refineSeparatedAffix\":true}"
Text=callApi(url, payload, tokenKey)

Answer (score 0):

The Api I used can process strings and the structure of payload to address a string for processing is like below:

```
payload = u"\""+SWremoved+"\""
```